# Mathematical induction of weak form and different versions

Tags: induction, intuition

> The statement $P(n)$ is true for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ if the following
>   conditions are satisfied,
>
> - $P(1)$ is true
> - For all $k\in\mathbb{N}$, if $P(k)$ is true, then $P(k+1)$ is true. (*)

While in some literatures, they use another second point

> - If $P(k)$ is true for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$, then $P(k+1)$ is true. (**)

What are the differences? Whenever I try to understand the both versions by looking at the domino example, they seem to equivalent. I suppose that (**) has been rewritten from (*), even though the wordings are different. The first version can be proven by the axioms of Peano. Though I prefer using the second version to prove some claims by induction.

Comment: I think they are essentially the same informal renderings of the induction principle. Possibly related:  https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/10021/why-are-induction-proofs-so-challenging-for-students/10057#10057

Comment: They both translate to $\forall k \in \mathbb{N} \,.\, P(k) \rightarrow P(k+1)$.  The reason for your preference, if I may speculate, could be that the second form suggests that one should look at a *generic* $k$ by instantiating the universal quantifier.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi I don't really see how the second version translate to as you say. Please enlighten me. I have another question. When trying to satisfy the second point, I would begin to assume $P(k)$ is true for some $k$. If I would express it another way, can I say "assume there exists $k$ such that $P(k)$ is true"? The reason I ask is because I fear that I might have used the quantifers in a wrong way/order.

Comment: Not only are they equivalent I'd say syntactically they are the same.  "If it's true for some value, it is true for the next value" is *exactly* the same thing as "for all values it is true for, it is true for the next".  There's no difference.  Not only in conclusion, but in basic meaning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's consider a variant of

> If $P(k)$ is true for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$, then $P(k+1)$ is true, $~~~~~~(**)$

namely the one we obtain by omitting the word "some:"

> If $P(k)$ is true for $k \in \mathbb{N}$, then $P(k+1)$ is true.

Do we believe that it captures the same condition as $(**)$?  If so we may then ask whether any natural number is excluded.  None, of course, because the only condition imposed on $k$ is membership in $\mathbb{N}$.  That means that the condition holds for all natural numbers $k$.  We can make it explicit by writing

> For all $k \in \mathbb{N}$, if $P(k)$ is true, then $P(k+1)$ is true.

Rewriting this condition as a sentence of first-order logic finally gives:

> $\forall k \in \mathbb{N} \,.\, P(k) \rightarrow P(k+1)$.

Suppose, however, that we believe that the omission of "some" changes the meaning of $(**)$.  Perhaps the work "some" evokes the idea of *existential* quantification.

As you write in a comment, "Assume $P(k)$ is true for *some* $k$," which may be read, "Suppose there exists $k$ such that $P(k)$ is true."

The problem with this reading of $(**)$ is that existence is not what the second condition of induction is concerned with.  The existence proof is the *base* case.  When you prove $P(0)$, you prove that one $k$ for which $P(k)$ is true exists.  With the inductive step you show that *everywhere* in the infinite line of dominoes, a falling tile knocks out the next.

Yet another way to look at $(**)$ is to rewrite it as follows:

> If for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$, $P(k)$ is true, then $P(k+1)$ is true.

We have just rearranged things a bit, but now we are closer to translating this informal statement into a formal one.  The new arrangement highlights that whatever quantifier binds $k$ applies to both occurrences of $k$ (the one in $P(k)$ as well as the one in $P(k+1)$).  The statement is about the relation between $P(k)$ and $P(k+1)$, not about the existence of some $k$ such that $P(k)$ is true.